# How can I make a function in php that will have signature void myFunction()

Tags: php

By default php returns NULL for function that doesn't do anything.

For example:

```
1 <?php
2 
3 function foo() {
4     // Nothing here
5 }
6
7 var_dump(foo()); // the result will be NULL
```

I'm trying to implement an function that will have direct output and i don't need to return anything from inside the function, i what to obtain something like:

```
void var_dump()// it just only dumps information.
```

My function will generate a image but will not return any information. The image will be generated, after processing, using ImageJpeg($image) inside the function. The signature in php manual for imageJpeg is:

```
imagejpeg — Output image to browser or file
```

in this way I'll have output image and NULL returned from function. How can i avoid that. How can i obtain ONLY output image?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: PHP *always* returns a value from an expression, by default `null`. That doesn't need to stop you...

Comment: And what's stopping you from writing `function foo() { imagejpg(...); }`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP equivalent of a `void function foo()` is a regular function that simply has no `return` statement. Whether this function outputs anything or not is completely independent of that. A function may output something in any variety of ways *and* `return` a value, or either or neither. In concrete terms, this is a function with no return value which outputs an image:

```
function foo() {
    ...
    imagejpg(...);
}

foo();
```

What you may be confusing here is the difference between a *return value* and *output*. The output is what the program finally outputs to the user/stout/`php://output`. A function return value is what the function returns to the caller.

```
function foo() {
    echo 'Hello World';
    imagejpg(...);
    return 'foo';
}

$bar = foo();
```

This function visibly prints "Hello World" on your screen followed by some binary image. The function returns the string `'foo'` and the variable `$bar` now holds `'foo'`, but this is *not output*.

Comment: @Starlays You may *upvote* and/or *accept* helpful answers... :)

Comment: Sorry, i will when i`ll have carma.

Answer (score 2):

A function that directly outputs content can be done via `echo`, `print`, etc. For example:

```
function sayHello($name = null) {
    if ($name === null) {
       echo "Hello!";
    } else {
       echo "Hello {$name}";
    }
}

sayHello("Fred"); // outputs: Hello Fred
sayHello();       // outputs: Hello!
```